# return JSON list and PYTHON requests library

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I'm using python request module to get a JSON reponse from 3 different servers. The 2 JSON response look something like these:

JSON Response 1:

```
{"MaleName1":"John","MaleAge1":"1.40531900","FemaleName1":"Anna","FemaleAge1":"14"}
```

JSON Response 2:

```
{"male":[{"name":"John","age":"12"}],"female":[{"name":"Anna","age":"14"}]}
```

JSON Response 3:

```
{"male":[["John","12",[]],["Alex","13",[]],["Glenn","12",[]],["Patrick","14",[]],["Gerard","14",[]]],"female":[["Anna","14",[]],["Lena","12",[]],["Martha","13",[]],["Penelope","13",[]],["Brenda","13",[]]]}
```

My question is what is the correct approach to parse 2nd and 3rd JSON responses so I can print the following desired values:

```
1st Male Name: John
1st Male Age: 12
1st Female Name: Anna
1st Female Age: 14
```

For the 1st JSON response, I got no issue getting the desired response by using the ***float()*** argument below:

```
import json, requests

def 1stMaleName():
    1stMaleNameData = requests.get('url')
    return 1stMaleNameData.json()['MaleName1']
    1stMaleNameValue = float(1stMaleName())
    Print ("!st Male Name: ", 1stMaleNameValue)
```

Comment: Why do you need to parse the 3rd response, given all the information you need is in the second response?

Comment: @AChampion because 2nd and 3rd response will come from different sources, and the values can be different from each other, so I need to get data from both sources to make some validation.

Answer (score 1):

The second response can be parsed with:

```
In []:
ordinal = lambda n: {1:'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd'}.get(n%10, 'th')

d = {"male":[{"name":"John","age":"12"}],"female":[{"name":"Anna","age":"14"}]}
for k, v in d.items():
    for i, s in enumerate(v, 1):
        print(f"{i}{ordinal(i)} {k.capitalize()} Name: {s['name']}")
        print(f"{i}{ordinal(i)} {k.capitalize()} Age: {s['age']}")

Out[]:
1st Male Name: John
1st Male Age: 12
1st Female Name: Anna
1st Female Age: 14
```

And the 3rd response with:

```
In []:
d = {"male":[["John","12",[]],["Alex","13",[]],["Glenn","12",[]],["Patrick","14",[]],["Gerard","14",[]]],"female":[["Anna","14",[]],["Lena","12",[]],["Martha","13",[]],["Penelope","13",[]],["Brenda","13",[]]]}
for k, v in d.items():
    for i, s in enumerate(v, 1):
        print(f"{i}{ordinal(i)} {k.capitalize()} Name: {s[0]}")
        print(f"{i}{ordinal(i)} {k.capitalize()} Age: {s[1]}")

Out[]:
1st Male Name: John
1st Male Age: 12
2nd Male Name: Alex
2nd Male Age: 13
3rd Male Name: Glenn
3rd Male Age: 12
4th Male Name: Patrick
4th Male Age: 14
5th Male Name: Gerard
5th Male Age: 14
1st Female Name: Anna
1st Female Age: 14
2nd Female Name: Lena
2nd Female Age: 12
3rd Female Name: Martha
3rd Female Age: 13
4th Female Name: Penelope
4th Female Age: 13
5th Female Name: Brenda
5th Female Age: 13
```

Note: This `f-strings` work in Py3.6+. For .format(), e.g.:

```
f"{i}{ordinal(i)} {k.capitalize()} Name: {s['name']}"
```

Is equivalent to:

```
"{}{} {} Name: {}".format(i, ordinal(i), k.capitalize(), s['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

For your 2nd JSON query:
1) Iterate through the dictionary

2) Iterate through the list

3) Iterate through the dictionary in the list

That will bring you close to what you're searching.

Please see an [example](https://repl.it/repls/ProductiveVoluminousPlanes).